# auto expire information in a database

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I have a temp mysql table that holds information until checkout on an ecomm site. I would like to be able to delete the expired table data after 72 hours how would i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store a `datetime` at creation. Periodically (*via job process for instance*) run a query to delete all records where `datetime` is less than `now - 3 days` ago.

```
DELETE FROM `Table`
WHERE `CreatedOn` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

I think it's worth mentioning that unless storage volume is an issue, preserving this data may prove valuable for marketing analytics.

Comment: @MichaelBenavides Markup? For what?